# Strange messages on startup after the latest update

Tags: updates, hp

After installing the latest kernel update for Ubuntu 22.04 (5.15.0-41-generic) on my laptop (HP Laptop 15s-eq2xxx) I started to get strange messages on startup. Everything works fine so far but I am still worried. Should I do something with it or just leave it be?

[image]

Comment: If the OS boots properly and otherwise seems to be working fine, you can safely ignore boot errors/warnings. They are perfectly normal and not something you have to worry about.

Comment: @Esther, okay, thanks!